# Xamarin.Forms - Should the provisioning profiles be added to the solution for iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, provisioning-profile

I have a Xamarin.Forms app (Android and iOS) and I have deployed this on App Center.
The provisioning profile and personal information exchange (so .mobileprovision and .p12) are of course loaded in the build on App Center, but they are added in the solution as well. Everything works, but I'm wondering one thing: should the provisioning profile and personal information exchange be added to the solution as well? It seems that it should work without those two in the solution, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, There is no reason to have them as part of the solution. HOWEVER, I haven't deployed via App Center - perhaps that needs them.

On each one, check `Properties`. If

- `Build Action` = `None`, and
- `Copy to Output Directory` = `Do not copy`,

then leave them alone - they won't be included in the app, so it is ok.

Comment: The Build Action is None and the Copy to Output Directory is Do not copy, so I simply removed the files from the solution and did a rebuild. That seemed to work just fine, but I'll test things tomorrow.